# I use physics to find the position of the objects, but then I can't save and go on

Tags: physics

beginner here :-)
I am trying to use rigid body physics to set objects' initial position. At first I was puzzled because I got to the end of the animation and could not even change the material or the color of the objects. Then I understood that I had to do that at the beginning, or "bake the animation", which I did and this allowed me to change the final position and few other things. However... I must be doing something wrong. In fact, I need to adjust the position of the objects to my liking, and I do so by rotating and moving the objects one by one. Many light bulbs are in the wrong position because I am using CAPSULE instead of MESH to speed up the process. So I must tilt the position by hand. However, and this is my problem, once I adjust the final position to my liking, if I save the file, and then open it, I find the objects in the position they were before my adjusting it. Even worse, if I render the scene, the position does not reflect my adjustment.
I am attaching an image of the problem. You can see that in the viewport the position of the light bulbs in the foreground has been fixed, but in the final render they are wrongly placed horizontally.
[image: what I see, with the light bulbs in the right position]

[image: the render with the bulbs in the wrong position]

Comment: Hi marco! a few questions: why don't you change the objects to mesh instead of capsule? the physics simulation is pretty quick and i cannot really believe this takes a long time to animate? or did i misunderstood you? and why can't you just change the color at the beginning of the animation? and maybe it is a good idea to provide your blend file so we can check it out.

Comment: Perhaps my mesh was  complex or my M1 Mac too slow but using a capsule led to a big improvement in fluidity. Eventually, yes, I changed colours and other stuff at the beginning, but anyway I found out that by baking, I could still change colours afterwards. As well as positions... however, I could not save the blend file once I made these changes or, worse, I could not render the image with the objects repositioned! I agree that if I had to start over all again, I would use mesh but still... I cannot understand if there is a way to make further adjustments after all the objects have settled.

Comment: turn on statistics and you see how much vertices and faces u have....but your geometry does not look that complex. But of course, if it has 100.000 vertices each...it will definitely slow down. But this has nothing to do with your M1 Mac. I use an older mac and with these simple physics i had never performance problems. But yes...you have to use reasonable geometry. With "too" much geometry you will kill every computer - even if it is the fastest of the world.

Comment: and again - you can still use your settings. e.g. you could use remesh modifier to reduce your geometry. Then you can use mesh in physics and you do not have to "correct" every bulb manually because it will fall physically correct

Comment: if you provide your blend file, i can check it out - on a mac ;)

Comment: Many thanks for the offer. I put my blend file on google drive. As I said the main problem for me here is understanding why, if I move the light bulbs and save the file and/or render the scene, I do not see the persistence of the adjustments.
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o2sKG0VToUd7D35eQKBpKP8pOLwSDewU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: And do you share the link to your google drive...?

Comment: Because you animated them via physics. You cannot do both - physics and manual adjustment at the same time (same frame). What you could do is turn the physics off for your last frame. Then you could adjust them.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I am not that familiar with stackexchange but I believe I did share it on Gdrive. Turning off the physics for my last frame... this is something that I had not tried, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of issues in your file - this is not really a solution, but a start from which you should begin - in my opinion.

First - please watch tutorials about rigid body physics. I am assuming, that this is one of your first rigid body physics animations because you made a lot of things which an experienced user would not do.

What do i mean with that?

1. your objects aren't really separated (which is a situation which does not exist in reality) so some of your objects are overlapping at the start of your simulation. So what should Blender do with intersecting objects? Well...Blender does weird things with it, it is like dividing through 0 -> you can't do it. And in reality things do not overlap.
2. your objects have much too high subdivisions which isn't necessary for such an easy object. You should try to use as less subdivisions as possible, because more subdivisions mean: more used memory, less performance, more thing to calculate for Blender.
3. if you do not have basic shapes you always should use mesh as collision objects, else the physics looks weird and not realistic
4. start using physics with ONE object and check out whether it works. Then add more. Check performance. If it slows down dramatically as in your case, you did something wrong (too much subdivisions in your case). you can decrease your subdivision by using a remesh modifier.
5. decrease the margin for the collisions to 0, else it won't look really realistic.
6. Really watch or read tutorials/books/manuals about blender and rigid body physics. Learn from others instead of trying out yourself because it will save you lots of time. Blender is - in my opinion - not intuitive, but an amazing too. Lot's of people went to the problems you now have - learn from them and save time.
7. if you did all this - you don't have to manually move your objects, because they will fall down physically correct and realistic. and in a reasonable speed.
8. you did not apply transforms

Comment: Number 8 especially :-) Thanks for all. Yes, I am at the very beginning. O:-)

Comment: no problem. we all started once. and i made these mistakes too -  a lot of times ;)

Comment: start with simpler scenes - so you stay motivated. But if you keep going, a lot of frustration is waiting for you...but even more excitement and happiness ;) Blender is amazing! ;)